# What is this device?

Tags: utensils

[image]

What is this device called? The length is exactly 12 inches.

Comment: It would be great to provide some kind of reference for the size (a ruler for instance)

Comment: I recommend registering your account - then you can [edit] your posts as needed. See [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) and [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for more information.

Answer (score 66):

I don’t know if it has an official name, but it’s a spaghetti tool. The holes are for measuring portions and the tines are for stirring in the boiling water and for serving after it’s strained.

Comment: It's a "plastic pasta server/measurer" on alibaba
https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/PLASTIC-PASTA-SERVER-PLASTIC-PASTA-MEASURER_60418792997.html

Comment: I can also confirm this answer. My mom had one of these when I was a kid in the 80's-90's.

Answer (score 0):

This tool is certainly labelled as a pasta server/measurer on Alibaba. It doesn't look useful for such, though. It looks more like an herb stripping tool.

Here's a [link on amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F74RRH5) to a similar product.

Comment: Other than identifying the tool as "like an herb stripping tool",  this answer just plain wrong. It looks similar to the herb-stripping tool, because form follows function, and the mechanical aspects are similar. But the tool being asked about is **definitely** a pasta tool, and is **definitely not** an herb-stripper. It is larger than an herb-stripper, the holes are typically marked specifically for pasta serving sizes, and the spoon shape provides a means for picking up not just spaghetti, linguini, etc. that the tines work with but also smaller pasta shapes.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'd add as well that the other central claim of this answer is _also_ definitely wrong - the tool does look useful for pasta serving/measuring.

Comment: My guess is this item is way too big for herb stripping, but it's admittedly hard to tell from the picture.

Comment: @PeterDuniho you put a handful of spaghetti through the holes, to get 1/2/4 servings or perhaps 100/200/300g or some such.  Very quick and convenient.  The prongs let you fish spaghetti out of the water easily.  I would say it's not a general-purpose pasta tool, but one limited to long pasta for the fishing, and  to long hard pasta for measuring, and even then best at spaghetti (with round cross-section giving a predictable area) and worse at long hard flat noodles (where packing could give more or less solid a cross section than spaghetti).

Comment: @Swiss: you don't need to explain to me how to use the tool. I have one that I've owned for 30+ years. And I have found it useful for dealing with all types of pasta. YMMV.

Comment: @PeterDuniho apologies, meant to direct comment to Aww_Geez.  That said, not sure how you'd measure macaroni or fish out lasagna with this!  :-D

Comment: @Swiss: you got me there on the lasagna. I let my wife make that dish. But, I never said it was used for _measuring_ all types of pasta, just that I find it handy as an alternative to e.g. a slotted spoon (i.e. "dealing with") for the smaller pastas.

Comment: It's not really useful for anything. It's a gimmick, and if you order your salad spinner *now*, it comes free +$29.95 in shipping. We'll even throw in a second one that you can give to your friends, who will find it as equally useless.

Comment: @Mazura salad spinners are very handy.